Wrong matrix assigment in Python?
I have this code:
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import numpy
import math

inputfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

atoms = numpy.zeros((6, 3), dtype='float64')
for line in inputfile:
    sline = line.split()
    header = sline[0]
    for i in range(1, 4, 1):
        atoms[i] = float(sline[i])
        # print(float(sline[i]))
print(atoms)

The content of the input file is:
 O5    -2.978    -1.342     0.528
 C1    -4.475    -1.062     0.491
 C2    -4.710    -0.049    -0.519
 C3    -4.193     1.266    -0.144
 C4    -3.045     1.113     0.856
 C5    -2.268    -0.070     0.555

I want to extract the coordinates and save them in a matrix called atoms. But, the content of the matrix that I am getting is:
[[ 0.     0.     0.   ]
 [-2.268 -2.268 -2.268]
 [-0.07  -0.07  -0.07 ]
 [ 0.555  0.555  0.555]
 [ 0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.   ]]

What is wrong with this code?

You can see from the output that the code is assigning to the wrong parts of the matrix, so what do you need help with exactly? What have you tried? For example, have you read the NumPy user guide, Indexing on ndarrays?

But why are you doing it the long way in the first place? Why not just use loadtxt()?

@wjandrea how will you do it? Please, share an answer.

You read each line of the file and split it into 4 strings.  You skip the first sline[0] (so far ok).
But then you iterate through the remaining strings, and assign the float version to rows 1, 2, and 3 of atoms:
for i in range(1, 4, 1):
    atoms[i] = float(sline[i])

i.e.
atoms[1,:] = float(sline[1])
atoms[2,:] = float(sline[2])
atoms[3,:] = float(sline[3])

And  you repeat that for each line, overwriting three rows of atoms each time.  atoms[0] is all 0's, the original value.
The last line is
 C5    -2.268    -0.070     0.555

and those are the values in atoms[1:4,:].  Everything you did with the previous lines has been overwritten.
While I could suggest a fix, I think you should work it out yourself.  You aren't doing anything fancy, so as long as you are careful with the details, you should be able to do.
I like to work in an interactive python session, such as ipython, and test a line or block one at a time.
As a hint, start with i=0, and step it with each new line.  For one line write something like
for j  in range(3):
    atoms[i, j] = float(sline[j+1])

In other words, you need a separate counter for rows and columns of atoms.  You may later be able to assign whole rows of atoms at once, but for a start get the details of the row by row, column by column assignment correct.

atoms is a 2D array, but you are only indexing it with one index, so atoms[i] refers to an entire row. When you assign a scalar to (a slice of) an array like that, the scalar gets "broadcast", i.e, repeated as many times as necessary, to fill out the entire slice (i.e, in this case a row).

Thank you for your explanation and what do you propose to solve the issue? How should I modify the code?

I'm not sure why someone downvoted this. All the info is correct, though it's not a complete answer since there are more things wrong with the code.

@Another.Chemist You didn't ask for a solution in the question, you only asked what's wrong. If you want a solution, edit the question to clarify that.
